# Improve performance for large PPT Slide-Copy task

Tags: vba, scripting, ms-office, powerpoint

Here is the thing: I need a VBA script that generates power point presentations from others. The main difficulty here are the large file sizes. The final PPTs are going to contain up to 1000 slides each. I have to open the initial PPTs and re-sort them to tell the long story short.

A huge factor will be the reopening task. I can not open all those files at once at this point since the machine would run out of memory very quick.

Is there somhow a time saving or memory saving method to fulfil this task? Since this task is mainly a re organizational thing there might be a way to accomplish my needs.

I would be thankful for any help.
Best regards.

Comment: A better description of the problem would help. Are you bringing ALL of the slides from each of the sub-presentations into the main one and then sorting somehow, or ???   And "reopening task" ... reopening what?  Note that you can use ActivePresentation.Slides(x).MoveTo(y) to move slide x to position y.  Very quickly.

Comment: Hi Steve! There are for example 10 to 20 presentations that contain have some criteria such that in the end only 4 presentations as a mix of the initial ones are obtained as a result. I know that sorting slides inside a presentation is very fast. But i have to create a new one and copy different slides into that new ppt. Since these files are quite large I am afraid that the final script might run very slow because I'd have to open these ppts one after another and save them to the hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to insert slides from one file into another, you either need to open the source file yourself or let PPT do it implicitly behind the scenes.

If you let it do the work (ie, by using the Slides.InsertFromFile method) you can only insert contiguous ranges, and for each invocation of the method, PPT will open/close the file.  If you need to work with non-contiguous ranges, you'll save time by opening the file (windowless if you like) and managing the copy process yourself.  That way you can do a bit of pre-sorting and open each source file only one time.

Also, current versions of PPT will open files considerably faster if they're saved as PPTX rather than PPT, I've noticed.  The difference isn't especially apparent with small files but can become quite noticeable as files get larger.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I'll keep that in mind as soon as I continue coding!